# Anatomically Correct Night Land Monsters

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, biochemistry

[The Night Land](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/10662) features a far future landscape, where the sun has gone out, which is made treacherous by the presence of various non-human "forces" and "powers", and monstrous creatures waiting to attack the unwary traveler.

Of course, William Hodgson didn't know about nuclear fusion or stellar evolution--and really, a future Earth orbiting a dead sun would be orbiting a white dwarf, with a surface temperature somewhere around 40-50K. Rather chilly to support creatures based on contemporary biology.

But suppose something evolved to live there and threaten spacesuited travelers walking the surface. How might such creatures function and survive? (If necessary, assume that sometime in the preceding billion years, humans found it convenient to do some biological engineering and introduce artificial lifeforms that could survive on the cold Earth, which have since evolved out of control; they do not need to be based on carbon and/or water.)

**Details:**

- The atmosphere of the dead-sun Earth is very thin, and composed on hydrogen, helium, and neon.
- Water, oxygen, nitrogen, and carbon dioxide are common surface minerals.
- Illumination from the white dwarf sun is about 1/1000th of what the contemporary Earth receives--so full sun at noon is still 400 times brighter than a contemporary full moon. Plenty bright enough to see by, and to support (slow) photosynthesis.
- Some creatures must be mobile, but need not be extremely active; if an individual can chase down a lone human in a burst of energy once every thousand years, that's just fine.

This question is part of the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about creatures in an already built 3rd party world, instead of asking about building a fictional world.

Comment: @sphennings Except... it's not. It's inspired by a 3rd party world, but the question is clear that it is asking about a very different setting than the one actually portrayed in that 3rd party work.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley "[In keeping with the Stack's general rule of not fielding questions about 3rd party or commercial worlds, the ACS is now limited to questions about documented myths and legends of Humanity and creatures thoroughly designed for a fictional world of the OP's own creation.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/80336)".[...]

Comment: [...] But that doesn't mean your question shall be closed, because your actual question is "How can I have human predators on a chilly planet's basking in the dark?" (no 3rd party), not how "how can I believably make this specific kind of monster?" (all 3rd party), which by the way you don't describe at all! I'm voting to close until this confusion is cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

**Plutoforming.**

[image: pluto]

https://www.americaspace.com/2016/03/23/pluto-once-had-rivers-and-lakes-of-liquid-nitrogen-new-horizons-data-suggests/

It got too dark out on Pluto.  But the inner planets cooled off nicely and so the Plutonians moved in.  Plutoforming Venus and Earth made them in some respects nicer than Pluto ever was for the relocated Plutonians.

The Plutonian predators big enough to threaten an unwary human are all sessile ambush predators.  Life forms are mostly small and so no predators are huge.  They might take a leg.  They might unsessile enough to come get the rest of the human where it fell a little ways off.  That should be enough to keep that one sated for a few years.

Comment: Did these Plutonian predators find any prey on Earth ? Or do Plutonians have to wait until a human in space suit arrives..

Comment: @Goodies - Plutonian prey.  The Plutoformers moved the detritivores first because Earth still had that from before.  Then Plutonian plants, then the herbivores, then the carnivores.   Then I showed up fresh from Nova Terra, the warmest thing for hundreds of square kilometers, not paying attention to where I put my feet.

Comment: That seems to just shift the question to "how do Plutonians work?"

Answer (score 1):

**Hydrothermal Vents**

There are already ecosystems on Earth that are separated from the sun. For example tube worms feed off the energy released by hydrothermal vents.

[image]

Of course a tube worm cannot snatch a human out of its shoes. But it's not just tubeworms down here. Look closer -- there is a ghost crab and some small orange Pokemon hiding in there.

[image]

Your Night Land Monsters have as the bottom of their food chain something akin to smokers. I leave it to your imagination how the smokers got so close to the surface that the denizens ever encounter humans.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. Have I read the question too fast and overlooked some part that says "no tubeworms"?

Comment: Being able to encounter humans is kind of a big part of the problem, but you got my upvote.

Comment: I imagine the vent is near the surface of Dead Earth and not in the deep ocean.

Comment: There could be surface hot springs and volcanoes. Then it would be more probable for humans to encounter the creatures.

Comment: @GrandPhason Hmm . . . yes a smoker near the surface might be something like a mineral spring

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet would probably be for some form of silicon based life. They could withstand much colder temperature than anything carbon based, and are much more likely to form on a planet with no gaseous oxygen. The base of the food chain would probably be comprised of chemosynthetic organisms, and may use some compound such as liquid methane or ethane. They could also potentially have incredibly slow metabolisms, and could have very strange compared to carbon life.

Comment: Methane is solid at those temperatures, so they'd need a significant energy source to maintain a liquid interior environment.

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting to write very quickly, and neglected to fact check. Taking a second glance, I cannot find anything other than Fluorine that could be a liquid, but only by 2 degrees. There is also little room for change in temperature. Perhaps organisms could find a way to maintain body temperature and use either liquid fluorine or oxygen, which could be hard. They could also operate with no liquid, which may be possible. On the topic of energy, there may be a few photosynthesizers, but with a dim sun, there probably would be many organisms that break down certain chemical materials

Comment: F2O works as a liquid (it's what Robert Forward proposed in _Camelot 30K_), but yeah, there's not a whole of options!